# HTTP WCF Service via HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf

I have a C# Web Application project that is secured using Forms Authentication. Managing the Authorization of various pages using the default Role Manager is working well.

I've recently added a number of WCF (*.svc) services to the project which I call using Javascript from the browser using ASP.NET AJAX (adding a ScriptManager referencing the service). This all works fine using HTTP.

I have now added a HTTPS binding to IIS with a certificate and am attempting to use the application via HTTPS; however the pages that reference the service throw up a '401 Unauthorized' error when they try and load the js proxy class (service.svc/jsdebug). From what I've gathered I need to change the configuration in my web.config file to make it work, but I can't find any settings that will get it working. I need it to be accessible via HTTP protocol (enableWebScript), but via HTTPS. It also needs to use the identity of the currently authenticated Forms user.

Any general advice on configuring the endpoints in web.config would also be appreciated - or a pointer to a good tutorial. Thanks

**Here is the services section of my web.config file at present**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WsHttpBindingConfig">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttp">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="default"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webScriptEnablingBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="scorelink.groups.Risk">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="scorelink.tests.Benchmarks">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="default">
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehaviours">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider" membershipProviderName="SqlProvider"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles" roleProviderName="SqlProvider" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="scorelink.groups.Risk">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="scorelink.groups.Risk"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="scorelink.groups.Risk" />
      </service>
      <service name="scorelink.tests.Benchmarks" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehaviours">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="scorelink.tests.Benchmarks"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="scorelink.tests.Benchmarks" />
      </service>
      <service name="scorelink.services.user" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehaviours">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="default" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBindingConfig" contract="scorelink.services.Iuser" />
        <endpoint address="http" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webScriptEnablingBehavior" bindingConfiguration="webHttp" contract="scorelink.services.Iuser" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

It might be a bit confusing since I've tried so very many things. I am only focusing on `user.svc` at the moment, but once it's working I'll apply the configuration to all the services.

**EDIT**

I updated my config to one suggested but now get the following error:

```
The endpoint at 'https://localhost:44300/_assets/code/services/user.svc' does 
not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion. 
System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior' is only intended 
for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.
```

I assume that this is because it is using an endpoint behaviour that specifies `<enableWebScript />`. The problem is if I take that away then the service doesn't generate a javascript proxy class so I can't call it from js.

**EDIT 2**
Here is a dump of the js proxy class that is generated by ASP.NET in response to the EnableWebScript flag. It is accessible from `http://uri/service.svc/jsdebug`:

```
Type.registerNamespace('scorelink.services');
scorelink.services.Iuser=function() {
scorelink.services.Iuser.initializeBase(this);
this._timeout = 0;
this._userContext = null;
this._succeeded = null;
this._failed = null;
}
scorelink.services.Iuser.prototype={
_get_path:function() {
 var p = this.get_path();
 if (p) return p;
 else return scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.get_path();},
CreateUser:function(FirstName,LastName,Username,DateOfBirth,Roles,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
/// <param name="FirstName" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="LastName" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="Username" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="DateOfBirth" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="Roles" type="Array">System.String[]</param>
/// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'CreateUser',false,{FirstName:FirstName,LastName:LastName,Username:Username,DateOfBirth:DateOfBirth,Roles:Roles},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
UpdateUser:function(username,firstName,lastName,dateOfBirth,roles,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
/// <param name="username" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="firstName" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="lastName" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="dateOfBirth" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="roles" type="Array">System.String[]</param>
/// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'UpdateUser',false,{username:username,firstName:firstName,lastName:lastName,dateOfBirth:dateOfBirth,roles:roles},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
DeleteUser:function(Username,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
/// <param name="Username" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'DeleteUser',false,{Username:Username},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
GetUserDetails:function(Username,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
/// <param name="Username" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'GetUserDetails',true,{Username:Username},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
ChangePassword:function(oldPassword,newPassword,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
/// <param name="oldPassword" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="newPassword" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'ChangePassword',false,{oldPassword:oldPassword,newPassword:newPassword},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
ChangeLockoutCode:function(password,symbol1,symbol2,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
/// <param name="password" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="symbol1" type="Number">System.Int32</param>
/// <param name="symbol2" type="Number">System.Int32</param>
/// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'ChangeLockoutCode',false,{password:password,symbol1:symbol1,symbol2:symbol2},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); }}
scorelink.services.Iuser.registerClass('scorelink.services.Iuser',Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy);
scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance = new scorelink.services.Iuser();
scorelink.services.Iuser.set_path = function(value) {
scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.set_path(value); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.get_path = function() { 
/// <value type="String" mayBeNull="true">The service url.</value>
return scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.get_path();}
scorelink.services.Iuser.set_timeout = function(value) {
scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.set_timeout(value); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.get_timeout = function() { 
/// <value type="Number">The service timeout.</value>
return scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.get_timeout(); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.set_defaultUserContext = function(value) { 
scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.set_defaultUserContext(value); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.get_defaultUserContext = function() { 
/// <value mayBeNull="true">The service default user context.</value>
return scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.get_defaultUserContext(); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.set_defaultSucceededCallback = function(value) { 
 scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.set_defaultSucceededCallback(value); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.get_defaultSucceededCallback = function() { 
/// <value type="Function" mayBeNull="true">The service default succeeded callback.</value>
return scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.get_defaultSucceededCallback(); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.set_defaultFailedCallback = function(value) { 
scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.set_defaultFailedCallback(value); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.get_defaultFailedCallback = function() { 
/// <value type="Function" mayBeNull="true">The service default failed callback.</value>
return scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.get_defaultFailedCallback(); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.set_enableJsonp = function(value) { scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.set_enableJsonp(value); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.get_enableJsonp = function() { 
/// <value type="Boolean">Specifies whether the service supports JSONP for cross domain calling.</value>
return scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.get_enableJsonp(); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.set_jsonpCallbackParameter = function(value) { scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.set_jsonpCallbackParameter(value); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.get_jsonpCallbackParameter = function() { 
/// <value type="String">Specifies the parameter name that contains the callback function name for a JSONP request.</value>
return scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.get_jsonpCallbackParameter(); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.set_path("http://localhost:5584/_assets/code/services/user.svc");
scorelink.services.Iuser.CreateUser= function(FirstName,LastName,Username,DateOfBirth,Roles,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {
/// <param name="FirstName" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="LastName" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="Username" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="DateOfBirth" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="Roles" type="Array">System.String[]</param>
/// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.CreateUser(FirstName,LastName,Username,DateOfBirth,Roles,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.UpdateUser= function(username,firstName,lastName,dateOfBirth,roles,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {
/// <param name="username" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="firstName" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="lastName" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="dateOfBirth" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="roles" type="Array">System.String[]</param>
/// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.UpdateUser(username,firstName,lastName,dateOfBirth,roles,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.DeleteUser= function(Username,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {
/// <param name="Username" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.DeleteUser(Username,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.GetUserDetails= function(Username,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {
/// <param name="Username" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.GetUserDetails(Username,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.ChangePassword= function(oldPassword,newPassword,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {
/// <param name="oldPassword" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="newPassword" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.ChangePassword(oldPassword,newPassword,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
scorelink.services.Iuser.ChangeLockoutCode= function(password,symbol1,symbol2,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {
/// <param name="password" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="symbol1" type="Number">System.Int32</param>
/// <param name="symbol2" type="Number">System.Int32</param>
/// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
scorelink.services.Iuser._staticInstance.ChangeLockoutCode(password,symbol1,symbol2,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
var gtc = Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy._generateTypedConstructor;
if (typeof(scorelink.services.UserDetails) === 'undefined') {
scorelink.services.UserDetails=gtc("UserDetails:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/scorelink.services");
scorelink.services.UserDetails.registerClass('scorelink.services.UserDetails');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are few things which you need to confirm :

- You have self signed certificate.
- You have required SSL checked.
- You    have Edit Bindings -> Type is Https -> Port is 443(default
  port).
- Security Mode.
- endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"
- some custom code in Page.aspx.cs    where you are accessing service.

Comment: (1) the site runs under a self-signed certificate with the public key installed on local machine. (2) I do not have require SSL checked because I'd like it to be accessed from HTTP AND HTTPS. (3) The site is bound to :80 and :443 using the self-signed cert. (4) Not sure what 'security mode' is - do you means Forms Authentication? (5) I've seen a few references to a mex binding, but it doesn't generate the js proxy class. (6) the code to access the service is javascript via the proxy class.

Comment: I meant Security Mode is whether Transport, Message, etc.(as per need) Use Message & clientcredentialtype=username. Which binding exactly you are using? Can you put piece your js proxy class?

Comment: Please see ammendments at the end regarding the proxy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on a brief review of the information provided, the configuration file does not seem to define the security correctly.  For example, the following snippet:

```
    <binding name="WsHttpBindingConfig">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
```

... should probably look like:

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name=" WsHttpBindingConfig">
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
            </security>
```

The following links provide good background information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648840.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59927/WCF-Service-over-HTTPS-with-custom-username-and-pa

Regards,

Comment: I've read through both those links and they are interesting, but don't exactly solve my problem. The first link (MSDN atricle) resulted in me getting no js proxy class, thus the service was unusable - the service did bind to https though. The second guide was also interesting, but also yielded no results. Both focus more on authenticating with a specified username and password as opposed to passing in an already authenticated identity from ASP.NET. Thoughts?

Comment: The following SO Q/A seems to address the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531100/how-can-i-pass-logged-on-user-details-from-asp-net-web-app-to-wcf-service

Comment: Thanks for spending time on this. I had a look at the Q/A and it's a similar problem, but it is consuming the service using c# - I am consuming it using Javascript, and therein lies the problem: I have no c# methods available to me.